# Drop down value populate input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having issues changing some code to work on another area but slightly different.

The example in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/A8Nxp/354/ shows the original code but now I need it do something different

I have list of years so when one is selected I need to the price to appear in the empty textbox beside it. Each option has its own price.

```
<div align="right">Year Required </div>
</td>
<td><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap years-required"><select name="years-required"       class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true">   
<option value="">---
</option><option value="00/01">00/01</option>
<option value="01/02">01/02</option>
<option value="02/03">02/03</option>
<option value="03/04">03/04</option>
<option value="04/05">04/05</option>
<option value="05/06">05/06</option>
<option value="06/07">06/07</option>
<option value="07/08">07/08</option>
<option value="08/09">08/09</option>
<option value="09/10">09/10</option>
<option value="10/11">10/11</option>
<option value="11/12">11/12</option>
<option value="12/13">12/13</option>
</select></span>  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap price">
<input type="text" name="price" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="pricetwo" aria-required="true" />
</span></td>
```

EDIT price list

01/02 - £150

02/03 - £135

03/04 - £120

04/05 - £105

05/06 - £90

06/07 - £75

07/08 - £65

08/09 - £64

09/10 - £63

10/11 - £62

11/12 - £61

12/13 - £60

Just need help modifying the jQuery in the jsFiddle example to meet the needs above.

EDIT
I can not change the value of the options as I am using Contact Form 7 plugin with wordpress. So require the prices to be in the jQuery. Example 01/02 selected £150 appears in text field.

Comment: Cant you just set the price in the value property?

Comment: What are the prices to go with those years?

Comment: I need to be able to display the price on screen when a customer selects the year required and for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I don't find any price value in your code.
2) But I think, you're trying to display the value of **`select`** element in the **`textbox`**

**`.val()`** Here I used to get the **current value** of the selected option/textbox.

**`change`** Here I have binded the `change` event with **`.on()`** event Handler attachment like

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('#pricetwo').val($(this).val());
});
```

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Nxp/356/)

**Updates:** The value of option, need not to be same as innerHTML.

so change the select values like this

```
  <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="1">00/01</option>
    <option value="2">01/02</option>
    <option value="3">02/03</option>
    <option value="4">03/04</option>
    <option value="5">04/05</option>
    <option value="6">05/06</option>
    <option value="7">06/07</option>
    <option value="8">07/08</option>
    <option value="9">08/09</option>
    <option value="10">09/10</option>
    <option value="11">10/11</option>
    <option value="12">11/12</option>
    <option value="13">12/13</option>
```

Here is an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Nxp/358/)**

Comment: @addy88 It is simple, you can do it by yourself by changing the values in the JSFiddle I have created.  It will help you to understand better.

Comment: This works but the reason I want it like the example in the post is that I am unable to change the value in contact form 7 plugin on wordpress. I need the prices to be in the jQuery so for example 01/02 is selected it will choose the prices that matches it. Does that help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set price in `value` of each `option` in `drop-down`. for ex :

```
<select name="years-required" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true">   
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="£150">01/02</option>
<option value="£135">02/03</option>
<option value="£120">03/04</option>
<option value="£105">04/05</option>
<option value="£90">05/06</option>
<option value="£75">06/07</option>
<option value="£65">07/08</option>
<option value="£64">08/09</option>
<option value="£63">09/10</option>
<option value="£62">10/11</option>
<option value="£61">11/12</option>
<option value="£60">12/13</option>
</select>
```

for more hits: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/3D28z/)

Comment: This works but the reason I want it like the example in the post is that I am unable to change the value in contact form 7 plugin on wordpress. I need the prices to be in the jQuery so for example 01/02 is selected it will choose the prices that matches it. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your values, you could add an additional `data-` attribute (HTML5)

HTML snippet

```
<option data-price="£11.99" value="1">1</option>
<option data-price="£12.99" value="2">2</option>
and so on...
```

JQuery:

```
$('#payslips-required').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var price = selected.data('price');
    $('#price').val( price );
});
```